# Django Template logic

Tags: django, templates

So I am just now getting to grips with Django,

I want to something relatively straughtforward. I have a model thus:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    volnumber = models.IntegerField(db_column='volNumber')
    title = models.TextField()
    keywords = models.TextField(blank=True)
    start_page = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_page = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    author_1 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author_2 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author_3 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author_4 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author_5 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author_6 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author_7 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author_8 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author_9 = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author_10 = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

in my view:

```
def index(request):
    article_list = Article.objects.all()
    volume_list = Volume.objects.all()
    auth_list = ['author_1', 'author_2', 'author_3', 'author_4', 'author_5', 'author_6', 'author_7', 'author_8', 'author_9', 'author_10', ]

    return render_to_response('index.html', {
            'article_list': article_list,
            'volume_list': volume_list,
            'auth_list' : auth_list,
    })
```

and I want to iterate over the first articles authors, as well as eliminating empty entries for the list in the template:

```
<ul class="articleList">
    {% for article in article_list %}
        <li>
        {% for author in auth_list %}
            <i>{{ article."author" }}</i>
        {% endfor %}

        {{ article.title }}{{ article }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

obviously that doesn't work, and I'm not sure the template is the place for this logic, but I hope from this it is clear what I am trying to achieve.

Any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have enough author fields for your Articles?  You might need more!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure you want to design a list of authors that way. If you want multiple authors, consider using a new model for Author and then using a ManyToManyField in your Article class to link articles to authors. Then, you can loop through authors in your template like so:

```
{% for author in article.authors.all %}
    <!-- blah blah -->
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the Author model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.TextField(...) # don't copy to ..., put whatever params you need
    last_name = models.TextField(...)
```

and the adjusted Article model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    # add this line
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

Now you do not need to return an `auth_list` in your view code.

Comment: And with the new model it's a lot easier to organize the articles by author as well.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. I did realize the models didn't look too nice, though in my defense they were legacy models from existing data. I think it would be worth my effort to change that though. Thanks for the swift answers - it all seems straightforward one the models are designed correctly. Cheers all!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your data model (although I strongly advice you to follow @andrew-lee suggestion) you are not allowed to call-by-name attributes in the templates. You should do:

```
# in the view
return render_to_response('index.html', {
        'article_list': article_list,
        'volume_list': volume_list,
        'auth_list' : [getattr(article, name) for name in auth_list],
})

# in the template
    {% for author in auth_list %}
        <i>{{ author }}</i>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on what has already been said, it makes the most sense to change your model, but if you want to keep it as-is and display a list of only the author fields which have been filled in, you might do this in the template:

```
<ul class="articleList">
    {% for article in article_list %}
        <li>
        {% for author in auth_list %}
            {% if author %}
            <i>{{ author }}</i>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {{ article.title }}{{ article }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```